# Job status in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have created a DAG with 3 tasks. One of the task failed so in airflow UI the job is shown as failed. But when I do a backfill of the previous tasks. They now succedd but the status of the JOB still remains unchanged it still shows failed even though the individual tasks have succeeded. Am I missing out something?[image]

Answer (score 0):

`backfill` in airflow doesn't work similarly to the scheduler runs. The `backfill` command doesn't create dag runs but simply queues the tasks of the dag. The scheduler however creates dag runs in the db and uses them to schedule tasks. Therefore, when the `backfill` is done, no actual dag run objects are created/updated in the db hence the circle remains in its old color (state).